# Network controller unclaimed only in Recovery

Tags: networking, drivers, nvidia, recovery-mode

An update to the Nvidia drivers causes my Ubuntu 22.04.1 (Kernel 5.15.0-53) to not boot beyond a black screen with a blinking cursor, and most suggestions to resuscitate this involve purging and installing a different driver from the recovery (or using Ctrl Alt F1-7 on the black screen).

However, I am not able to connect to the internet at all.

`lspci` shows my WiFi adapter, but

`nmcli dev status` only shows the `lo` device (unmanaged), and `lshw` lists my network controller as being unclaimed.

None of these issues happen when I boot into a previous version of the kernel; the output of `nmcli dev status` shows both the WiFi controller as well as external Ethernet adapters. Is there a way to manually load the drivers for these? Restarting `NetworkManager` has not helped.

Thanks!

(P. S. I know that I can just use the previous version of the kernel to roll back the driver, but I would like to fix this issue for if/when an update breaks both kernels)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-53-generic | grep Status` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: This kernel upgrade had the same impact on me (although I could boot from recovery mode even though I had access to only one of my displays). Here's the output from `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-53-generic | grep Status` on my machine (when booted using 5.15.0-52): `Status: install ok installed`

Comment: @dianced Please start your own new question.

Comment: @chili555 I apologize for not responding sooner. That was, in fact, the root of the problem - the extra modules weren't installed for some reason. After re-installing the 5.15.0-53 kernel and the extra modules, everything works fine (display as well as internet connectivity). If you would like to reply with an answer, I would be happy to accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you confirmed in your comment, linux-modules-extra was not installed. From an earlier working kernel version, please do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-53-generic
```

Reboot. You should be all set.